# How to sum up one column and then group by the summed up column

Tags: sql, oracle, sum, window-functions

I have a table with the following

```
Col A          
10
20
30
```

I want this result

```
Col A         Col B
10             60
20             60
30             60
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `sum` in its analytic version:

```
SQL> with test (cola) as
  2    (select 10 from dual union all
  3     select 20 from dual union all
  4     select 30 from dual
  5    )
  6  select cola,
  7    sum(cola) over () colb        --> this
  8  from test;

      COLA       COLB
---------- ----------
        10         60
        20         60
        30         60

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add sum over analytical function you will get desired result.

```
select colA,sum(colA) over() colB from Table;
```

Comment: How different is this from the answer posted by @Littlefoot 3 hours ealier?

Comment: I didn't see other answers, simply posted it, although it is same...

Answer (score 0):

With your sample data:

```sql
WITH tbl (COL_1) AS
(   
    SELECT 10 FROM Dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 20 FROM Dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 30 FROM Dual
)
```

... you could select the sum as a subquery column:

```sql
Select    COL_1, ( Select Sum(COL_1) From tbl ) "COL_2"
From      tbl 
Order By  COL_1
```

... or you could join your table with the sum subquery

```sql
Select  t1.COL_1, t2.COL_2
From    tbl t1
Inner Join (Select Sum(COL_1) "COL_2" From tbl  ) t2 ON(1 = 1)
Order By t1.COL_1
```

Both resulting as:

```sql
     COL_1      COL_2
---------- ----------
        10         60
        20         60
        30         60
```